# No tachanun after shkiah?

Tags: sources-mekorot, tachanun, mincha-afternoon-prayer

Many siddurim in my possession indicate one who davens minchah after sunset omits tachanun. What are the sources behind this ?

Comment: Note that many _chasidim_ don't say _tachanun_ even __close to__ _sh'ki'a_.

Comment: @msh210, I'm aware, however there are questions which address that here, IIRC. The practice of those who say tachanun by minchah not doing so after shkiah isn't addressed by any of those AFAIK

Comment: Same reason people don't usually say slichot (aka tachanunim) before midnight.

Comment: As a personal שאלה, I emailed R' Hamburger of Machon Moreshes Ashkenaz, who told me that although he hasn't published his monograph on the subject, the correct practice among German Jews is to recite tachanun on days when it should be said, regardless of whether minchah is prayed before or after sunset

Comment: @msh210 https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21&st=&pgnum=29 "i was once in a shul that didn't say tachanun an hour before sunset and I yelled at them but they wouldn't listen...and the shulchan aruch says we say slichot after midnight because it's close to day and this is no worse"

Answer (score 4):

(Sources [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.131.3?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=he).)

Shulchan Aruch (Orach Chaim 131:3) writes:

> ‏אין נפילת אפים בלילה...:

> There is no "Nefilat Apayim" [what we consider to be "Tachanun"] at night...

Mishnah Berurah there (note 16, based on Beit Yosef) argues that this ruling is based on kabbalistic reasons. There is a general discussion as to when halachic night begins; while Mishnah Berurah (note 17) rules that during the period of "Bein Hashmashot" one is still permitted to say Tachanun (based on Taz there), Kaf Hachaim (note 51) makes a very strong argument against it based on various sources, and primarily the Magen Avraham there (which Mishnah Berurah cites, but must interpret differently).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119815/discussion-on-answer-by---no-tachanun-after-shkiah).